# How to get a new number from original number?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a range of numbers from 0 to 9. Now in the below code, I am getting a number which will be between 0 and 9 inclusive.

```
int number = getRandomNumber(); // this will give me number between 0 and 9 inclusive
int newNumber = ....
```

Now basis on `number` variable, I want to generate a `newNumber` which should also be between 0 and 9 inclusive. This `newNumber` will be -2 of original `number`.

- Now let's say I get `number` as `5`. Then I need `newNumber` to be `3` which is -2 of original number.
- Now let's say I get `number` as `2`. Then I need `newNumber` to be `0` which is -2 of original number.
- Now let's say I get `number` as `9`. Then I need `newNumber` to be `7` which is -2 of original number.
- Now let's say I get `number` as `1`. Then I need `newNumber` to be `9` which is -2 of original number.
- Now let's say I get `number` as `0`. Then I need `newNumber` to be `8` which is -2 of original number.

What will be the logic for this so that I can get my `newNumber` which will always be -2 of original number and will be in between 0 and 9.

Basically my confusion is how to get right value for 1 and 0 case.

So for `1` case if I subtract `-2`, I will get `-1` but that is not right answer I want to be in between 0 and 9 so I am not sure what will be the logic here?

Comment: if less that 2 add 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward.

```
newNumber = number -2;
if(newNumber < 0) newNumber = newNumber+10;
```

Answer (score 4):

One more approach is

```
int newNumber = (10 + number - 2) % 10;
```

Comment: I always admired the power of modulo. +1